# into run flutter web i have issue ' Expected a value of type 'SkDeletable', but got one of type 'Null'' any solutions?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

my code is only UI and i use below packages:

provider: ^5.0.0

bubble: ^1.2.1

image_picker: ^0.7.4

image_cropper: ^1.4.0

Comment: Show your code where the error occur and not your pubspec content

Comment: I suggest reading [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

best answer

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77258

"Something's wrong with memory management in ImageFilter or any thing other. It's trying to garbage-collect null. Does this problem happen only in --debug mode, or also in --release and --profile?"

so run web into release mode

flutter run -d chrome --debug

flutter run -d chrome --profile

flutter run -d chrome --release